# ORA-22912 specified column or attribute is not a nested table type /oracle creating nested table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, nested-table

I was working with OODB and tried to make a nested table using two tables. I am posting code here

```
create type BranchType as object(
address AddrType,
phone1 integer,
phone2 integer );

create table BranchTableType of BranchType;

create type PublisherType as object(
name varchar2(50),    
addr AddrType,
branches BranchType);
```

The code intends to create a table branch by branch type and then creates a type Publisher Type which then try to create a nested table.

```
create table Publishers of PublisherType NESTED TABLE
branches STORE as branchTable
```

But the above code gives error saying that the specified type is not a nested table type. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up your types, between objects, tables of objects, and object tables. This builds, with a made-up `addrtype` since that wasn't described in the question:

```
create type addrtype as object(
city varchar2(20)
)
/

create type BranchType as object(
address AddrType,
phone1 integer,
phone2 integer )
/

create type BranchTableType as table of BranchType
/

create type PublisherType as object(
name varchar2(50),    
addr AddrType,
branches BranchTableType)
/

create table Publishers of PublisherType NESTED TABLE
branches STORE as branchTableTypeStore
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7639).

The main differences are:

```
create type BranchTableType as table of BranchType
```

as a table **type** rather than a table, instead of:

```
create table BranchTableType of BranchType;
```

And:

```
create type PublisherType as object(
...
branches BranchTableType)
```

with the nested table **type**, instead of:

```
create type PublisherType as object(
...
branches BranchType);
```

And:

```
branches STORE as branchTableTypeStore
```

as a storage **name** not type, instead of:

```
branches STORE as branchTable
```

But I'm not entirely sure what you'll be doing and if this is exactly what you want. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction anyway...

Comment: Thank you so much i wanted to do the same work but wasn't able to do that. I was messed up with the branch type and messed my work. But really Thank you Very much.