# Oracle : Nested table inside a type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, nested-table

I need to create table with an O_BIEN attribute. O_BIEN type includes a nested table of T_HABITANT type.

Here is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_HABITANT AS OBJECT (
    estmajeur CHAR(1),
    lien      VARCHAR(10)
);
\

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_HABITANT AS TABLE OF O_HABITANT;
\

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_BIEN AS OBJECT (
    surfacetotale NUMBER(3, 2),
    nombrepices   VARCHAR(2),
    habitant      T_HABITANT
);
\

CREATE TABLE FISC (
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    bien O_BIEN
)NESTED TABLE bien STORE AS NST_BIEN;
```

I've the following error:

> ORA-22912: specified column or attribute is not a nested table type"
>   *Cause:    The storage clause is specified for a column or attribute
>              that is not a nested table column or attribute.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid nested table column or attribute.

So, how can I specify the habitant attribute of O_BIEN as a nested table ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-22912 specified column or attribute is not a nested table type /oracle creating nested table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785647/ora-22912-specified-column-or-attribute-is-not-a-nested-table-type-oracle-creat)

Comment: No because O_BIEN is actually a non instantiable type. There are two others types which extend O_BIEN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me when I specified full column name with alias:

```
create table fisc (id number primary key, bien o_bien) 
  nested table bien.habitant store as bien_habitant_store;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle with test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c99680592f1d7dc439d9f019a38da7da)</sup>**